# Retrieve phone numbers from customer

Tags: php, sql, count

The customers can have 3 different phone numbers, and I want to retrive these from the database, based on the numbers in my array phone.

```
function statsUserRing($phone, $link)
{
    $i = 0;
    $p1 = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $phone[0]);
    $p2 = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $phone[1]);
    $p3 = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $phone[2]);

    while($get_stats = $link->get_object("SELECT REPLACE(telnr,'-', '') as telnr FROM ringupp WHERE telnr LIKE '%$p1%' OR telnr LIKE '%$p2%' OR telnr LIKE '%$p3%'"))
    {
        $i++;
    }

    return $i;

}
```

Im trying with a customer that have 2 phone numbers registred. So my array contains 2 values, which is these numbers.

Those 2 numbers appears 16 times in my ringupp table, but when I run my code above, it counts it to 204154. Why?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that your 3rd phone number is an empty string, so your final clause becomes `OR telnr LIKE '%%'`, which will return everything.

Comment: Yes, in this case the 3rd phone number is an empty string. The customer can have 1, 2 or 3 numbers. How should the query be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using only SQL:

```
SELECT  REPLACE(telnr,'-', '') as telnr 
FROM    ringupp
WHERE   (telnr LIKE '%$p1%' AND '$p1' <> '')
OR      (telnr LIKE '%$p2%' AND '$p2' <> '') 
OR      (telnr LIKE '%$p3%' AND '$p3' <> '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for nulls and add the conditions to your query based on that:

```
$query = "SELECT REPLACE(telnr,'-', '') as telnr FROM ringupp";

if($p1 != null)
    $conditions = "telnr LIKE '%$p1%'";
if($p2 != null)
    if($conditions != "")
        $conditions = $conditions + " OR ";
    $conditions = $conditions . "telnr LIKE '%$p2%'";
if($p3 != null)
    if($conditions != "")
        $conditions = $conditions . " OR ";
    $conditions = $conditions . "telnr LIKE '%$p3%'";

if($conditions != "")
    $query = $query . " WHERE " . $conditions + ";"
```

Comment: @Racii Hillan: Thank you for your answer. Is this the only way? So I cant use the OR and AND operators?

Comment: @user500468 I'm not sure what you meant by "I cant use the OR and AND operators?". I used the `OR` above. Did you mean that you want to achieve in the query directly without checking the parameters one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that checks for empty values and constructs a SQL query dynamically:

```
function statsUserRing($phone, $link)
{
    $i = 0;
    $count = 0;

    $p[0] = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $phone[0]);
    $p[1] = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $phone[1]);
    $p[2] = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $phone[2]);

    foreach ($p as $k => $v){
        if (!empty($v)){
            if ($count > 0){
                $wherelogic .= "OR telnr LIKE '%$v%' ";
            } else {
                $wherelogic .= "telnr LIKE '%$v%' ";
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }

    $sql = "SELECT REPLACE(telnr,'-', '') as telnr FROM ringupp WHERE ".$wherelogic;
    while($get_stats = $link->get_object($sql))
    {
        $i++;
    }

    return $i;

}
```